# How to create database with liquibase in UTF-8 character set

Tags: spring, utf-8, jhipster, liquibase

Working with Jhipster (Spring) and Liquibase and I want liquibase to create my database if doesn't exists and I want it to be in UTF-8.

Here is a sample of my "application-dev.yml" config file.

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/scalink?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    name:
    username: root
    password:
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
```

My question is now : Where am I wrong ?

Thanks to all.

Alex

Comment: I would think that this has to be done when you create the database in MySQL workbench before Liquibase and Jhipster creates objects in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Liquibase CORE-50](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-50) the creation of the database is not a task for Liquibase. Trying to create the database over the datasource url with the parameter **createDatabaseIfNotExist=true** is just an option which is offered by the JDBC driver. Unfortunately creating a database this way is limited in option. Also the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) does not provide more information. If you still want to create the database the way that you mentioned, you can let the database to be created over the JDBC url and then add a changeSet in the *config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml* which is altering the schema to utf8

```
<changeSet id="0" author="jhipster">
    <sql>ALTER SCHEMA `jhipstersampleapplication`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```